# How to work with dynamic code in java method?

Tags: java, dynamic, methods, redundancy

I have nearly redundant java methods. The body of these methods is always the same. Only one or two java expressions (java code lines) are different. I want to do a code refactoring of these nearly redundant methods, but I'm searching for the best way to do this. It's not so easy, because of the dynamic code lines.

Here are three methods with the same body but with dynmamic java code in it:

```
public static final boolean doSomething1() {
    Date date = new Date();
    long currentTime = date.getTime();
    long maxTime = currentTime + (TIMEOUT * 1000);

    while (currentTime < maxTime) { 
        try {
            //START OF MY DYNAMIC CODE
            //example 1
            for (WebElement element : list) {
                if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                    element.click();
                    return true;
                }                   
            }
            //END OF MY DYNAMIC CODE
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("exception");
        }
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    return false;
}

public static final boolean doSomething2() {
    Date date = new Date();
    long currentTime = date.getTime();
    long maxTime = currentTime + (TIMEOUT * 1000);

    while (currentTime < maxTime) { 
        try {
            //START OF MY DYNAMIC CODE
            //example 2
            for (WebElement webElement : webElementList) {   
                WebElement parent = getParentElement(webElement);
            }
            return true;
            //END OF MY DYNAMIC CODE
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("exception");
        }
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    return false;
}

public static final boolean doSomething3() {
    Date date = new Date();
    long currentTime = date.getTime();
    long maxTime = currentTime + (TIMEOUT * 1000);

    while (currentTime < maxTime) { 
        try {
            //START OF MY DYNAMIC CODE
            //example 3
            for (WebElement element : list) {
                if (element.isDisplayed() && element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(size))
                    return true;
            }
            //END OF MY DYNAMIC CODE
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("exception");
        }
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    return false;
}
```

So, how is it possible to write one method with the opportunity to set the dynamic lines of code?

Comment: What part of our code should actually be "dynamic"? There is no way to make `if (false == true)` dynamic. The only thing you can do is make the condition in your if statement dynamic.  But in your last examole there are two dynamic lines `System.out.println("test"); if ("test".equals("test"))` and this will not work at all.

Comment: I changed my code to make it more clear what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Example using [`BooleanSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BooleanSupplier.html) as Strategy:

```
private static boolean doSomethingHelper(BooleanSupplier checker) { 
    Date date = new Date();
    long currentTime = date.getTime();
    long maxTime = currentTime + (TIMEOUT * 1000);

    while (currentTime < maxTime) { 
        try {
            if (checker.getAsBoolean())
                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("exception");
        }
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    return false;
}

public static boolean doSomething1() {
    return doSomethingHelper(() -> true);
}

public static boolean doSomething2() {
    return doSomethingHelper(() -> false);
}

public static boolean doSomething3() {
    return doSomethingHelper(() -> {
        System.out.println("test");
        return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a boolean parameter whose value is the first operand of the `X == true` (which is more easily written as `X`):

```
public static final boolean doSomething1() {
  return doSomethingCommon(true);
}

public static final boolean doSomething2() {
  return doSomethingCommon(false);
}

private static final boolean doSomethingCommon(boolean param) {
  // ...
  if (param) {
    return true;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @Martin try asking the question you want answering first time.

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices:

1. Aspect oriented programming
2. Strategy design pattern
3. Lambdas in JDK 8.

I'd prefer that last one.  Everyone should be using JDK 8 now.

I hope lines of code like this are just hastily written poor examples, not typical of the way you write:

```
        if (true == true)
```

Comment: it's only an easy example to show my problem. my real code is not the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [*Template Method* design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
abstract class DynamicImpl {

    protected abstract boolean doSomethingImpl();

    public final boolean doSomething() {
        Date date = new Date();
        long currentTime = date.getTime();
        long maxTime = currentTime + (TIMEOUT * 1000);

        while (currentTime < maxTime) { 
            try {
                if (doSomethingImpl()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("exception");
            }
            currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this class in place you can do your static methods as follows:

```
private static final DynamicImpl d1 = new DynamicImpl() {
    protected boolean doSomethingImpl() {
        return true;
    }
};

private static final DynamicImpl d2 = new DynamicImpl() {
    protected boolean doSomethingImpl() {
        return false;
    }
};

private static final DynamicImpl d3 = new DynamicImpl() {
    protected boolean doSomethingImpl() {
        System.out.println("test")
        return true;
    }
};

public static final boolean doSomething1() {
    return d1.doSomething();
}
public static final boolean doSomething2() {
    return d2.doSomething();
}
public static final boolean doSomething3() {
    return d3.doSomething();
}
```